# Show that n^2 is Big Omega(n lg n)

Tags: asymptotics

Also,

is n O(n lg n)?

I'm trying to understand this notation to better understand Big O. (Apparently they ask you questions about Big O in interviews, so I wanted to learn). I found a few formulas that I didn't understand.

Comment: What do you think? What did you try? Did you look at the definition of Big (Oh/Omega/Theta)?

Comment: @Juho Well I know that Omega means greater equal and theta means is or equal and O means lesser equal. I'm thinking it isn't because isn't lg n another growth rate? It confuses me because of the n in front of the lg n.

Comment: @Frightlin That's a rough intuition at best. Check out the *definition*, and our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth).